# Share pdf on web view to another devices using swift code

Tags: swift, pdf, web, view

I have a WKWebView which displayed pdf.  I want to share the file to another devices such as iPad, iPhone....  using the share button.  I tried to display the pdf in preview so it will have the iOS share button the code below.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ShowPDFView: UIViewController, UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate {

@IBAction func SharePDFFile(_ sender: Any) {

        let fileName = "testPDF"
        guard let urlPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "pdf") else {return}
            let controller = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: urlPath)
            controller.delegate = self
            controller.presentPreview(animated: true)

    }

 func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(controller: UIDocumentInteractionController!) -> UIViewController! {
            return self
        }

        func documentInteractionControllerViewForPreview(controller: UIDocumentInteractionController!) -> UIView! {
            return self.view
        }

        func documentInteractionControllerRectForPreview(controller: UIDocumentInteractionController!) -> CGRect{
            return self.view.frame
        }
```

I got runtime error.

```
[MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
```

The preview does not loaded.  Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

This function works for me.  In Swift 4

```
@IBAction func SharePDFFile(_ sender: Any) {

        let fm = FileManager.default

        var pdfURL = (fm.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)).last! as URL
        pdfURL = pdfURL.appendingPathComponent("johnMilky.pdf") as URL

        //Rename document name to "myFile.pdf"
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("johnMilkyFile.pdf") as NSURL

        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: pdfURL)

            try data.write(to: url as URL)

            let activitycontroller = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url], applicationActivities: nil)
            if activitycontroller.responds(to: #selector(getter: activitycontroller.completionWithItemsHandler))
            {
                activitycontroller.completionWithItemsHandler = {(type, isCompleted, items, error) in
                    if isCompleted
                    {
                        print("completed")
                    }
                }
            }

            //activitycontroller.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivity.ActivityType.airDrop]
            activitycontroller.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
            self.present(activitycontroller, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }


    }
```